# Logout button not working in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, button, logout

I'm using laravel 5.2 framework and I have created auth with the `php artisan make:auth` command. I have this in my AuthController:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';
protected $redirectPath = '/students';
protected $loginPath = '/auth/login';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}
```

And these in my routes.php file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

    Route::get('/students/', 'StudentsController@showStudents');

    // Authentication routes...
    Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

    // Registration routes...
    Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
    Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
});
```

While logging in/registering everything works perfect but when i press the logout button nothing changes and I'm still logged in. What I want is to redirect to the auth/login view after clicking that Logout button. Please help.

Comment: Add your logout function, so we can see what's going on there.

Comment: public function getLogout()
    {
         return $this->logout();
    }

Comment: public function logout()
{
     Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->logout();
}

Comment: I found these while searching through the whole app. They're functions that autocreate when calling php artisan make:auth command. I mean i didn't write them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems come AuthController middleware since the default router name is " `logout` " and if you have change the name middleware will not recognized your router name.

You just need to keep the default name router OR fix your construct middleware.

```
Route::get('logout', [ 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout', 'as' => 'logout' ]);
```

In `Authcontroller`,

```
public function __construct(){
   $this->middleware('guest', [ 'except' => 'logout' ]); // Default router name is "logout"
}
```

Hope it will help you :-)

Comment: Thanks! It helped!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to AuthController.php

```
    public function getLogout(){
      return redirect('Auth/login');

}
```